# What's difference between ticks and bars (strategy.exit)?

Tags: pine-script

I can't understand what exactly ticks are, used in startegy.exit for:

*trail_points (int/float series) Optional parameter. Level of activation of the tracking stop (profit specified in the ticks). If specified, a follower stop order will be placed when the calculated price level (specified amount of profit) is reached. The offset (in ticks) to determine the initial price of the follower stop order is specified in the 'trail_offset' parameter: X ticks below the activation level to exit the long position; X ticks higher than the activation level to leave the short position. The default value is 'NaN'.*

What is the difference between ticks and bars ?

Does anyone have a good clear and simple explanation that I can understand?
Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take crude oil for example. It has tick size of 0.01$. You can buy it in multiple of this price only. So suppose if you have bought at 98.5$ and your profit ticks is 10 ticks then your profit price is 98.6$.